# Border у псевдоэлемента

Tags: html, css, border

Я что-то на такой мелочи запнулся, нужно сверстать вот такую вкладку, и всё бы ничего, но `border` вокруг цифры сделать не получается. Он его попросту игнорирует.

```css
section ul.tabs li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px bold #999;
  font-size: 20px;
}

section ul.tabs li::after {
  content: '2';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 17px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px bold #222;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
}

section ul.tabs li:hover::after {
  content: '2';
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ff6633;
}

section ul.tabs li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Новые</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">В работе</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">На рассмотрении</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Выполнены</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отменены</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Черновики</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Должно быть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал через псевдоэлемент, но `border` не срабатывает

Comment: У бордера нет 'bold', нужно 'solid'

Comment: @GlebKemarsky думаю на сегодня пора отдохнуть, Вы абсолютно правы.
Напишите, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Граница элемента не понимает значения `bold`, поэтому ваша инструкция игнорируется. Это видно через инспектор:

[image: скриншот]

Поставьте `solid` вместо `bold`.

Какие варианты возможны, можно посмотреть на https://webref.ru/css/border

Answer (score 1):

как подметил @GlebKemarsky : У бордера нет 'bold', нужно 'solid'

```css
section ul.tabs li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px bold #999;
  font-size: 20px;
}

section ul.tabs li::after {
  content: '2';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 17px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
}

section ul.tabs li:hover::after {
  content: '2';
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ff6633;
}

section ul.tabs li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Новые</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">В работе</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">На рассмотрении</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Выполнены</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отменены</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Черновики</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```